# Can someone explain how this recursion works?

Tags: python, recursion

I can't figure out how it works.

```
def exp(x,n): 
   if n == 0:
      return 1
   else:
      return x * exp(x, n-1)

print(exp(2, 4))
```

answer is 16.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's simple math question.

Comment: Two comments: 1. Have you tried to write *on paper* the execution? is not hard. 2. What would happen if `n` is negative?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
exp(2, 4) = 2 * exp(2, 3) 
          = 2 * ( 2 * exp(2, 2) )
          = 2 * ( 2 * ( 2 * exp(2, 1) ) )
          = 2 * ( 2 * ( 2 * ( 2 * exp(2, 0) ) ) )
          = 2 * ( 2 * ( 2 * ( 2 * 1 ) ) )
```

Answer (score 0):

Reduction by hand:

```
? print(exp(2, 4))
! calculate( exp(2,4) ) and print the result
? exp(2,4)   matches the definition:
  exp(x,n)   with x=2, n=4
! substitute the variables in the function's body:
  if 4==0: return 1
  else: return 2 * exp(2, 4-1)
! 4==0 is false
? 2 * exp(2, 3)
.........
  2 * ( 2 * exp(2, 2) )
.........
  2 * ( 2 * ( 2 * exp(2, 1) ) )
```

Can you complete the sequence?